# How do I use Presence Probes with agsxmpp and C#

Tags: c#, xmpp, openfire, google-talk, agsxmpp

How can I retrieve a contact's current presence information using XMPP Presence Probes?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
client.Send(new Presence{Type = PresenceType.probe, To = "user@server.com"})
```